# JsViews Checkbox binding from an inner loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, 2-way-object-databinding, jsviews

I am trying to get a two way binding for a checkbox in an inner loop using JsViews

Not sure if this is possible.

```
<div id="targetSelection"></div>
<script id="targetItem" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <b>{^{:text}}</b>
  <div id="answers_{^{:fieldName}}" class='collapse'>
    {^{for answers ~fieldName=fieldName}}
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-fieldName="{{>~fieldName}}" data-index="{{:index}}" data-link="{:selected}" checked="{^{:selected}}" /> {{:text}} : {^{:selected}}
    </label>
    <br /> {{/for}}
  </div>
  <br />
</script>
```

and the JS code:

```
var target = [{
  "fieldName": "GENDER",
  "text": "Gender",
  "answers": [{
    "index": 1,
    "text": "Male"
  }, {
    "index": 2,
    "text": "Female"
  }, ]
}, {
  "fieldName": "AGE",
  "text": "Age",
  "answers": [{
    "index": 1,
    "text": "15-19"
  }, {
    "index": 2,
    "text": "20-24"
  }, {
    "index": 3,
    "text": "25-29"
  }, {
    "index": 4,
    "text": "30-34"
  }, {
    "index": 5,
    "text": "35-39"
  }, {
    "index": 6,
    "text": "40-44"
  }, {
    "index": 7,
    "text": "45+"
  }, ]
}];

$.each(target, function(questionIndex, question) {
  $.each(question.answers, function(answerIndex, answer) {
    answer.selected = true;
  });
});

$("#targetSelection").html($.templates("#targetItem").render(target));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22q7z9n9/

I am also trying to fire an event when the checkbox is changed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the JsViews docs? You are calling the `render()` method, not the `link()` method, and are using **jsrender.js** not **jsviews.js**!

So you need to load jsviews.js as in [Example page](http://www.jsviews.com/#download/pages-jsv), and then write: `$.templates("#targetItem").link("#targetSelection", target);`

See http://www.jsviews.com/#jsv-quickstart

Once you have read the basics, you can continue along the lines of:

```
{^{for answers}}
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-link="selected" />
    {{:text}} : {^{:selected}}
  </label>
  <br />
{{/for}}
```

For the event, there are a few options including to bind directly to the input change event, or listen to observable changes in your data etc. (http://www.jsviews.com/#observe). See the examples...

Here is a working version http://jsfiddle.net/28Lezc9m/4/.

I also changed: `<div id="answers_{^{:fieldName}}" class='collapse'>` to `<div data-link="id{:'answers_ + fieldName" class='collapse'>` - as explained in [this tutorial sequence](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link).

Comment: That didn't work, I already tried that syntax, not sure if the inner loop is the issue:http://jsfiddle.net/28Lezc9m/

Comment: That's because as I said, you are not actually using jsviews.js. See my updated answer above, and the working jsfiddle...